# Method to block browsing certain URLs (HTTP GET) in the operating system level (for all applications)

Tags: .net, windows, macos, winapi, firewall

I'm looking for a way to block users running GET/POST requests to certain URLs on their machines (for all browsers and other web connected applications).

Most common method is to modify **hosts file**, but this is not working for us as it redirects the whole domain.

> 127.0.0.1 example.com

I want to **redirect just certain sub URLs of some domains**, not the whole domain. Something like this:

> 127.0.0.1/some/service/   example.com/some/url/

What would be the most efficient way to do it programmatically? Through firewall API, custom local proxy server, or some other interesting approach? Solution can have administrator access to the clients machines and it can also be constantly running background process/service (and have some overhead).

Ideas for both, Windows and OS X, are appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to use an HTTP firewall, since you're not blocking the IP address itself it needs to be something that filters HTTP requests (GET, POST, etc). The sort of question is really off-topic for Stack Overflow however.

Comment: Yes. I need to filter HTTP requests. Worts case scenario is to funnel all traffic through my own custom proxy or virtual network adapter, but this seems like too much overhead. I hoped to find some OS level solution which could be configured over API. I should quite common use-case for many applications, development tools, emulators etc...